# Difference between posix-search-forward and search-forward-regexp (need example)

Tags: elisp

In emacs lisp, there's the function `posix-search-forward` http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/POSIX-Regexps.html.

Does anyone have a full example showing its difference from `search-forward-regexp`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated, the posix functions find the longest match in all situations:

Given the text `aa` and the regexp `"a\\|aa"`, `search-forward-regexp` will find `a` and stop, while `posix-search-forward` will continue to backtrack over all alternatives and will find that `aa` is the longest match.

Also as stated, the posix approach is incompatible with non-greedy operators:

Given the text `aa` and the regexp `"a+?"` `search-forward-regexp` will find the minimal match `a`, but `posix-search-forward` will (greedily) find `aa`, simply ignoring the non-greedy modifier.